# Hibernate Correct Mapping Map

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I've the following classes in Hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MODEL")
public class Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment") 
    Long id;

  @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable
    (
        name="DEVICE_LiCENSE_ATTRIBUTE",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DEVICE")
    )
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="LICENSE_ATTRIBUTE",nullable=false)
    Map<String,SoftwareLicense> softwareLicenses = new HashMap<String, SoftwareLicense>();

}
```

And this is my embedded Class

```
@Embeddable
public class SoftwareLicense {

    @Column(name = "Type", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;

    @Column(name = "VALUE", nullable = false)
    private String value;
}
```

Now when I run Hibernate it trues to build Table

```
create table DEVICE_LiCENSE_ATTRIBUTE (DEVICE bigint not null, Type varchar(255) not null, VALUE varchar(255) not null, softwareLicenses_KEY varchar(255), primary key (DEVICE, softwareLicenses_KEY)) 

create table DMS_DEVICE_MODEL (id bigint not null, DESCRIPTION varchar(255) not null, DISPLAYNAME varchar(255) not null, UNIQUENAME varchar(255) not null, primary key (id), unique (UNIQUENAME))
```

My problem occurs when `DEVICE_LICENSE_ATTRIBUTE` table created.

Just look at DEVICE_LICENSE_ATTRIBUTE table:

`softwareLicenses_KEY varchar(255)` is nullable and Hibernate tries to create Composite Primary Key on row which is nullable.

```
primary key (DEVICE, softwareLicenses_KEY)
```

It works on some DB (HSQLDB), but switching my code to another environment (MS SQL 2008) gives me an error.

```
Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'DEVICE_LICENSE_ATTRIBUTE'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My Mapping was wrong:

The correct way to map it is to use map column attribute:

```
 @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @MapKeyColumn(name = "LICENSE_NAME", insertable = false, updatable = false) 
    @CollectionTable
    (
        name="DEVICE_LiCENSE_ATTRIBUTE",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DEVICE")
    )
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="LICENSE_ATTRIBUTE",nullable=false)
    Map<String,SoftwareLicense> softwareLicenses = new HashMap<String, SoftwareLicense>();
```

Home it will be helpful for somebody.